# Result type with generic Success Type

Tags: swift

I'm switching over a project from a custom Result type to the native Swift Result type and keep running into this - or similar - error messages:

`Member 'success' in 'Result<_, Error>' produces result of type 'Result<Success, Failure>', but context expects 'Result<_, Error>'`

```
protocol DataFetcher {
    func request<T>(completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void )
}

struct RandomFetcher: DataFetcher {
    func request<String>(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        let str = "Hello"
        completion(.success(str))
    }
}
```

The idea is to have make a bunch of generic Fetchers for different data extraction calls and to pass these to VC's who would have a `var fetcher: DataFetcher` property. The VC's know which concrete types they expect from their request. I can't use an `associated type` as I need to save a bunch of these in an array and I thought I could get away with just the generic implementation - but it almost seems as if the Result type being declared as a generic in the protocol, means that it won't accept when I specify it in the implementation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func request<String>(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
```

This is a classic generics mistake in Swift. This does not mean "request requires `T==String`." This means "there is an arbitrary type called `String` that this function accepts." There is no relationship between this `String` and `Swift.String`.

What you're trying to do here violates the protocol. The protocol says that the caller gets to pick any T they want. You can't conform to that protocol with a restricted T.

If you want the conforming type (RandomFetcher) to get to decide the type of T, then you have to use an associatedType (that's what associatedType means).

The thing you're trying to build is pretty common, but not trivial, and requires a different way of thinking about the problem. I walk through it step-by-step in [this series](https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol).

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes, during yesterday "Type Eraser" did show up in my search history. I still haven't quite figured it out - I am rusty (paternity leave). Your series on protocols are very well written - I still am unsure of which direction to take, could you "name" the hierarchy of the approach you think I am talking about. e.g. A Request with a generic return type and a RequestClient adhering to a Client protocol or similar, basically I need a little more help to figure it out myself.

Comment: The way you've described it, there's no good way to build this into a generic algorithm. The coordinator has no way to know (at compile time!) that a given DataFetcher would extract the data the the ViewController needs. So it can't know how to pair them without eventually doing a bunch of `as?` casting, which breaks the whole point. Rather than starting with "I want fetchers and consumers," create a few concrete examples of what you want, and see what duplicates.

Comment: Part of your mistake here is that VCs generally shouldn't be making requests anyway. They should be tied to a Model. They should tell the Model when it needs to do things ("fetch new items"), but they should not receive the result of that directly. They should just display whatever the Model currently is. When you build that, you'll probably wind up with places for generic code like you describe, but it won't be ViewControllers, and that will make a big difference in how you design it.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. I wholeheartedly agree -Sorting out a large mess with parentVC making 1/2 the requests, the childVCs making the other 1/2 and both doing data manipulation directly. Trying to draw a line in the sand and get all the business logic into `Interactors` and for now pass these to the childVCs to cut the relationships with protocols instead of the usual tight coupling. Next, get the underlying data through some Client - baby steps, I count 8 classes named *Manager so far and we passed 2500 LOC. Rethinking the design as I type in the 15 Interactors, I'll need those in any case.

Comment: I would think long and hard before creating 15 Interactors in a 2.5 kLOC program. At that scale, one Model and one APIController are probably plenty. I'd be very slow to create 15 of anything other than trivial data objects. I would advise against creating any protocol that has fewer than 3 implementations. I've seen way too many Swift projects get themselves in big trouble proactively abstracting into generic code before they really know what problem they're facing. The wrong abstraction is much worse than tight coupling. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Just a quick comment on the LOC. The program isn't 2.5 kLOC, all the individual viewControllers are... hence the need for splitting up over multiple refactor sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In this case an associated type is preferable

```
protocol DataFetcher {
    associatedtype FetchType
    func request(completion: @escaping (Result<FetchType, Error>) -> Void )
}

struct RandomFetcher: DataFetcher {
    func request(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        let str = "Hello"
        completion(.success(str))
    }
}
```